# python mock different instances

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I would like to know the difference between `pg.connect` and `pg.connect()` statements.

`pg` is a psycopg2 mock object and when I display the `dir`, it shows connect as its method.

```
class TestMock(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_mock_calls(self):
        import pprint
        pg = mock.MagicMock(psycopg2)
        print 'pg() object ', pg()
        print 'dir of pg = ', pprint.pprint(dir(pg))

        print 'dir of pg = ', pg.connect
        print 'dir of pg.connect = ', pprint.pprint(dir(pg.connect))

        print 'dir of pg = ', pg.connect()
        print 'dir of pg.connect() = ', 
        pprint.pprint(dir(pg.connect()))
```

Updates:-
One(pg.connect) is accessing the attribute and other one(pg.connect()) calling the function.

Now, how can I set the return_value of the execute method?

For example:- I need to mock the response of my execute method.

so, it should be pg.connect().cursor().execute.side_effect = someexception()

Comment: What's the difference between accessing an attribute and calling it?

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Comment: So how can that be answered without repeating the question? One is just *accessing* the attribute... the other is *calling* it, and giving you the return value.

Comment: thanks. I just updated my question to understand how to set the return value of my execute method.

Comment: And how does that relate to the rest of what you've written? What has led you to ask this in the first place; what did you try, and what happened? Where is the code under test, how does that mock get in there at all?

Comment: @jonsharpe Here is more detailed explanation on my issue...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705038/python-mock-postgres-connection .. I was planning to go step by step but I think its better to give a bigger context of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Python is pretty literal minded. The expression `pg.connect()` translates to:

1. Look up the name `pg`
2. Look up the attribute `connect` on that.
3. Call it with empty arguments.

So an expression `pg.connect` will obtain the method, but not call it. And, in fact, you can use that method as a regular value and pass it around, so `my_connect = pg.connect` is entirely valid, and you can later call `my_connect()`.

We can see what's going on with the `dis` module:

```
import dis
dis.dis(lambda: pg.connect())

 1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (pg)
             2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (connect)
             4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Since `Mock` wants to pretend to be different objects, it is overriding the standard `__getattribute__` and `__call__` and `__eq__` dunder methods. While objects have a normal way of providing attributes, `__getattribute__` lets a class do whatever it wants if an attribute is requested.

When you call it as `Mock(spec=psycopg2)`, it's going to do two main things differently than `Mock()`:

1. It adjusts its `__class__` field to claim to be `psycopg2`.
2. Check psycopg2 for valid properties and raise `AttributeError` if you try to get a field that isn't present.

But beyond that, it still behaves as a regular mock. If you call `yourMock.foo`, it doesn't know if it's a property or a method. It just returns a new `Mock` instance, and because that instance is callable, you can call it like a function.

Update: If you set spec on `Mock`, it's restricting the available attributes. To add an attribute not provided by spec, you just need to set it at init time:

```
cursor_mock = Mock(side_effect=psycopg2.DatabaseError)
Mock(spec=psycopg2.connect, cursor=cursor_mock)
```

You also wanted this behavior: `pg.connect().cursor().execute.side_effect = someexception()`. Generally, you'd alter the `return_value`:

```
cursor_mock = Mock()
cursor_mock.return_value.execute.side_effect = SomeException
# Same as:
cursor_mock = Mock(return_value=Mock(execute=Mock(side_effect=SomeException)))
```

You can also do `cursor_mock().execute.side_effect = SomeException`, but that pollutes `cursor_mock.mock_calls`.

*Small point: I use `Mock` for brevity, and `MagicMock` is the same, simply adding some dunder methods.*

Comment: Here is my actual issue ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705038/python-mock-postgres-connection